# Can we preview a content file?

Tags: visualforce, content

Earlier version there used to be an option to preview content files. but now there just seems to be only a screenshot.

I have a VF page which shows the some content files and i am looking to see if we can preview the document from within the VF page.

Earlier i had use the chatter js code to show the preview, but that doesnt seem to work any more as i think SF has removed the option of preview.

Another option i thought of was to use Google's docviewer

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=YOUR_DOCUMENT_URL"></iframe>
```

What would be the url  which can be used instead of **YOUR_DOCUMENT_URL** if at all it can be used for Salesforce content files.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you to know the URL format you need?:

```
https://davitamedicalgroup--devqa--c.cs70.content.force.com/
sfc/
dist/
version/
renditionDownload?
rendition=PNG&
versionId=0683D000000BLxo&
contentId=05T3D000001W4oh&
d=/a/3D0000004Do7/hAmdtLoKlnOvMBK.0rfAnktxVxPFvlcEMs0lvcor_LU&
oid=00D3D0000000cHx
```

Comment: Thanks for the format. Any idea what those parameters refer to ? specially d and oid. Is there any documentation regarding it? Doesnt this actually show the png?